# php.ini extension not found Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, server, php-extension

I am working on a Minecraft Pocket Edition server for windows 10 and am using PHP7. It is a local copy not running on a server and I need to add some extensions to it, the php.ini file i wrote defines a few extensions

```
extension_dir = ".\ext"
enable_dl = On
allow_url_fopen = On
extension=php_weakref.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_yaml.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

But I am running into a few errors namely

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.\ext\php_weakref.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.\ext\php_yaml.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

What am I missing, is it a thread safe vs non thread safe issue, or did I mess up the extension_dir?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure the DLL in the extension directory was compiled for the version of PHP you're using.

Comment: how do I find that info out?

Comment: Run a phpinfo() (or `php -i`) to check installed extensions

Comment: Thanks!! please post your comment as an answer so I can give you proper credit.